# Value of a number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-history, philosophy

How does one define a value of a number? What is the value of the number 4? Asked differently, how does one show that a certain number is greater than another number?

After this, one might ask how do you quantify a real number?

This is a bit philosophical, but questions I wondered how math gives a rigorous answer to

Comment: "How does one show that a certain number is greater than another number?" This will depend on your definition of number... "How does one define a value of a number?" "How do you quantify a real number?" I have no idea what these questions mean. What exactly do you mean by "value" and "quantify" here?

Comment: The main goal is to understand how do you claim that two numbers are in an inequality relation? They must have a certain property that makes them different (value? quantity?)

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the number itself and is primarely done through number construction, we construct all the numbers and through it we decide what constitute an equality and inequality. [This](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~kumar/courses/310-2009/peano.pdf) is an excellent document showing for natural numbers to rational numbers, the real numbers is a bit lacking but it gives a good view of how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Brief outline:

For natural numbers, we have operation "next", often written as $'$: $1' = 2, 3''=5$ and so on (or, rather, symbol $5$ is short for $1''''$). From that, we have well-known operation $+$, and for natural numbers, $a \ge b$ is, by definition, $\exists c: a=b+c$.

Rational numbers are defined as ordered pairs $(p,q)$, where $(p_1,q_1) \ge (p_2,q_2)$ is $(p_1*q_2 \ge p_2*q_1)$ ($p_i$ are integral, not natural, but order of integer numbers is rather obvious).

Real numbers can be defined differently (those different definitions produce essentially the same object). One way is this: for rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, let $A \subset \mathbb{Q}, B=\mathbb{Q} \setminus A, A \neq \emptyset, B \neq \emptyset$ and $\forall a \in A, b \in B, a \ge b$ (note that this is "rational" $\ge$ which we have defined). We can *define* real numbers as such pairs $(A,B)$, and $(A_1,B_1) \ge (A_2,B_2)$ is $(A_1 \subseteq A_2)$.